# JavaScript array indexes

Tags: javascript

I am using Angular1x and I simply want to create an array object with numeric indexes:

```
var unreadMessagesCookieObject = [];

unreadMessagesCookieObject[id] = {
     id: messageObj.id,
     lastNotified: moment.getTime()
};
```

All fine? Well no not really:

```
(6) [null, null, null, null, null, {…}]
0: null
1: null
2: null
3: null
4: null
5:
id: 1
lastNotified: 1601769147988
```

Why do I have an object with 5 `null` indexes. I want to write the Object to a cookie but not the 5 null values.

How can I create an array object with an arbitrary numeric index. Note that I cannot use 0 as my first index since I want to be able to search in the array object by an id.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does a new javascript array have 'undefined' entries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130654/why-does-a-new-javascript-array-have-undefined-entries)

Comment: Is this the result of a round trip through JSON? Anyway, it looks like you probably want an object (`= {}`), not an array (`= []`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS arrays are already list-like objects. Instead of trying to overwrite it's behavior I'd tell you to create a standard JS object instead.

```js
let unreadMessagesCookieObject = Object.create(null);

unreadMessagesCookieObject[id] = {
   id: messageObj.id,
   lastNotified: moment.getTime()
};
```

Working snippet:

```js
let unreadMessagesCookieObject = Object.create(null);

unreadMessagesCookieObject[5] = {
  id: 1,
  lastNotified: 1601769147988
};

console.log(unreadMessagesCookieObject);
```